# aggregations in case statement

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I am trying to do aggregations in case statement. I found 2 ways to do it. Can anyone say what the difference between the 2 is?

1. `(CASE WHEN Event = 5 THEN count(*) ELSE 0 END ) Follow_Count
   GROUP BY Event;`
2. `SUM(CASE Event WHEN 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Follow_Count`

Answer (score 5):

Your case 1 will produce a row for each event in the table (from your group by).  Your case 2 will just return 1 row.

Is there a reason that you wouldn't just write:

```
select count(*)
from my_table
where event = 5;
```

Answer (score 3):

Better would be:

```
count(CASE Event WHEN 5 THEN 1 END) AS Follow_Count
```

Because 
1) for count used own standart counter,
2) "else" not need (count don't count nulls)

Regards,
Sayan M.

Comment: Also, your first variant preferrable for group by only event, and second more flexible and could used in many variants, and with analytic functions

Comment: You could also do this with decode rather than case.  count(decode(Event,5,1)) As Follow_Count

Comment: I know, but it is equal(except nulls, which do not used in condition). So i decided leave case as is.

Comment: I knew you could put column names within the parenthesis but never realized an expression such as a case statement is also valid.

Answer (score 2):

There is no significant difference. You can decide for you which is better by comparing their execution plans.